# How to pass external scope variable to foreach function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want the domMatch to be visible inside for each arrow function, if the body of the function can see `this` of outer scope which in my full case is a class there should also be a way to pass domMatch object.

```
            let tr = document.createElement("tr");

            let domMatch = {};

            domMatch.status = this.status;
            ... other props


            Object.getOwnPropertyNames(domMatch).forEach(function (domMatchField, a, b, domMatch) { // domMatch is undefined
                let cell = tr.insertCell(-1);

                cell.innerText = domMatch[domMatchField];

            });
```

Comment: Don't add a parameter called `domMatch`, you should just be able to access it

Comment: Just a sidenote - you dont have any arrow functions in your code.

Comment: @Jamiec not anymore, thanks for corrrection I updated the q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to pass the variable `domMatch` through the callback function in [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) - this function accepts (at most) 3 arguments so of course the fourth will be `undefined`

Just omit that argument, and `domMatch` should be available inside the inner scope.

```js
var domMatch = {};
domMatch.status = "foo";

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(domMatch).forEach(function(key, index, arr){
   console.log("iterating over key:", key);
   console.log("index:",index);
   console.log("Original array:", arr);
   // Now the important bit!
   console.log("domMatch", domMatch);
});
```